# Which registry key is modified by Security Policy SeDebugPrivilege?

Tags: windows-8, windows-registry, group-policy

I'm trying to find the registry key(s) that are modified by the Security Policy "Debug Programs" - aka SeDebugPrivilege in Windows 8.

I remember once seeing a web page that would identify each registry key based on a policy setting, but cannot seem to find it.

All my searching for the SeDebugPrivilege registry key doesn't seem to provide any additional insight.

Does anyone know what key(s) are modified by this setting and/or how to find out?

Answer (score 0):

You can establish the registry key(s) a policy links to by consulting the reference lists given out by Microsoft:

[Group Policy Settings Reference for Windows and Windows Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=25250)

According to that list you won't find this one in the registry, as the "User Rights security settings are not stored in registry keys".

Answer (score 0):

Privileges are not in the registry (because that would leave a hole).

According to this page, it is possible (with suitable *current* privileges) to adjust privileges for a given process: [Topic: Tip: Easy way to enable privileges](http://forum.sysinternals.com/tip-easy-way-to-enable-privileges_topic15745.html)

For reference:

- [User Rights](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349804%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
- [Privilege Constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530716%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

SeDebugPrivilege is not a security policy at all. It's a user privilege.

The association between accounts and user privileges is stored in the SAM database. When you authenticate to an account that holds a privilege, that privilege is reflected in your process's security access token. This enables processes running with that token to use the debugging APIs.